# Tab key for recommendation

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image]

Hi, as see above, I would like to know which key I should click for recommendation.

Probably, is it "TAB"?

However, when I click "TAB", I could get Tabnine info.

Tabnine info is based on AI recommendation as below. It is not system recommendation.

[image]

Can I know how to do that?